# How to divide dollars and cents by a float number in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I'm new to Ruby and I have a task to implement a class that has two variables - dollars and cents. And it has to have a method to divide this amount by a float number.

```
class Money
    def initialize(d,c)
      @dollars = d
      @cents = c
   end
    def divide(num)
        @dollars=(@dollars.to_f / num)
        puts @dollars.to_s
        @cents=(@cents.to_f / num).round+(@cents.to_f-@cents.to_i.to_f).round
        puts @cents.to_s
        @dollars=@cents.to_i
        puts "After dividing by #{num}: #{@dollars},#{@cents}"
    end
end
m=Money.new(100,69)
m.divide(2.1)
```

However, this method doesn't calculate it correctly. The result is supposed to be 47,95, but it is 47,34. As you can see, it calculates dollars right, but fails to calculate cents. I have tried modulo operations but it fails as well.

Will appreciate any help!

Comment: Financial calculations tend to require accuracy and no floating point implementation offers a sufficient degree of accuracy. For financial calculations it is often advisable to use integers for all calculations. If you need decimal digits they are better implemented with formatting rather than using floating point values.

Comment: @AndyPreston I see. So how can I implement it with formatting?

Comment: These look like they should help: 1) https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/money/Money/Formatter 2) https://github.com/RubyMoney/money 3) https://andycroll.com/ruby/dont-use-floats-use-ruby-money-for-representing-currency/

Comment: Consider, as a minimum, using [BigDecimal](https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/bigdecimal) which avoids cooking up your own version of same.

Comment: PSA: `puts` will automatically convert to string, so the `to_s` calls are unnecessary. If you're interested in dumping the value for debugging, consider using `p` instead which is the equivalent of `puts x.inspect`.

Comment: Another thing to note is Ruby allows you to define operations like `+` and `/` using those methods. You can define `+`, `/`, etc. like [the core classes do](https://rubyapi.org/3.2/o/integer#method-i-2F).

Comment: Using floats for financial calculations is not a good idea. This simple example that surprisingly returns `false` tells you why: `0.10 + 0.20 == 0.30 #=> false`

Comment: No matter what, you need to define your rounding strategy first. For example, what should happen if you divide 101 cents by 102 cents? Then implement your calculations with BigDecimal or Real numbers, or keep values as cents until you need to store or display the cumulative value. Even without Float values dealing with money is tricky.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do this yourself rather than using gem libraries, you should work with integers rather than floats due to the inherent imprecision of the latter, which can lead to cumulative errors. You should also decide whether fractional cents should be rounded or truncated. Hint: most banks and merchants will round up on charges and truncate on payouts or making change.

Try the following:

```ruby
class Money
  def initialize(d, c)
    @cents = 100 * d.to_i + c.to_i
  end

  def dollars
    @cents / 100            # integer division truncates
  end

  def cents
    @cents % 100
  end

  def divide(divisor, round_method: :floor)
    if round_method == :floor
      Money.new(0, @cents / divisor)
    else
      Money.new(0, (@cents.to_f / divisor).send(round_method))
    end
  end

  def to_s
    d, c = @cents.divmod(100)
    "#{d}.#{'%02d' % c}"    # Format cents to two digits w/ leading zeros
  end
end

m = Money.new(100, 69)
puts m.divide(2.1)                          # 47.94
puts m.divide(2.1, round_method: :round)    # 47.95
puts m.divide(1000)                         # 0.10
```

As you can see, it produces your desired outcome if rounding is used, but differs by a penny if truncation (`floor`) is used.

Note that if you're using rounding, you have to step through float calculations but should immediately convert back to integers.